# How to access parameters of foreign key to display data in table in Angular application?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, angular, typescript

I want to display data from a foreign table named 'Committee' and 'Staff', in a table which lists 'Committee Member'. I tried accessing it with the help of dataSource but was unable to do so. The code which i have written is as follows :-

```
//member-detail-view.ts
dataSource: Committee = new Committee()
  dataSource1: CommitteeMember[] = []

// Listing all committee member here --> 
  listCommitteeMember() {
    try {
      this.committeeMemberService.getAllCommitteeMemberData().subscribe((data: CommitteeMember[]) => {
        console.log(data)
        if (data != null) {
          var resultBody = data
          if (resultBody) {
            this.dataSource1 = resultBody
            // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          }
        } else {
          console.log("error in fecthing the Committee member")
        }
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error in get method :", err)
    }
  }
```

member-detail-view.html

```
<!-- Committee Member List Table -->
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource1" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">

  <tr *ngFor="let item of dataSource1"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="header-row"></tr>

  <!-- Id Column  -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Staff Id Column  -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="staffId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.staffId}}</td> <-- "I want to access the name of staff here" -->
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

my backend code -->

```
static async getCommitteeMember(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        try {
            const _count = await committeeMemberRepository.count()
            const page: number = parseInt(req.query.page as string) || 1;
            const pageSize: number = parseInt(req.query.pageSize as string, 10) || 10;
            const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
            const committeMemberData = await committeeMemberRepository.createQueryBuilder('Committee Member')
                .skip(skip)
                .take(pageSize)
                .getMany();
            res.status(200).json({
                data: committeMemberData
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Internal Server Error"
            });
        }
    }
```